# Do I need remove my app's from store before enrolling in Apple Enterprise Account

Tags: ios

Earlier we had a app on App Store (Uploaded from Developer Account) ,but now apple has rejected this app & we are enrolling in Enterprise Account. During the enrollment process we receive error which states that - "We've withdrawn this enrollment because XYG Inc is already a member of the Apple Developer Program".
Should I remove my existing app form Dveloper Account first.

Comment: A company can be a member of both the Enterprise program and have a company membership of the app-store program (My employer is).  You do need different Apple IDs to "own" each of the memberships, but contributor Apple Ids can be associated with both memberships.   Any difficulties should be referred to Apple developer support.

Comment: this error doesn't seems to be related with your app, check if you are enrolling for enterprise account only